# How I can specify mime types for media in imsmanifest.xml file?

Tags: scorm

I am preparing SCORM package and I have problem with some mediatypes.
When running inside SAP authoring tool .mp4 file is served as "media" mime type. When playing in Reload player I can see that .mp4 is served as text/plain. Is there a way to specify mime types in imsmanifest.xml file?
Here is a snippet for resources in my imsmanifest.xml file:

```
<resource identifier="RES_COMMON" type="webcontent" adlcp:scormtype="asset" href="content_frameset.html">
    <file href="runtime_media/picture/shared/rm100.png" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_1_3.mp4" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_1_3.nor.vtt" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_2_3.mp4" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_2_3.nor.vtt" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_3_3.mp4" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_3_3.nor.vtt" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_4_2.mp4" />
    <file href="runtime_media/video/nor/statoil_risk_module_4_2.nor.vtt" />
</resource>
```

Comment: I suspect this is more likely to be solved via server configuration rather than in the imsmanifest file. Where are you running the reload player from?

Comment: On my desktop. For reload player you can fix this by configuring server to serve mp4. Open <user_home_dir>\reload\reload-scorm-player\server\conf\web.xml file and add following bellow last mime-mapping tag: 

<mime-mapping> 
     <extension>mp4</extension> 
     <mime-type>video/mp4</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>

But I have no fix for SAP Authoring tool.
So I am wondering if there is a way to specify mime type inside xml manifest file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIME types are handled by the server serving the content, they are independent of SCORM and the imsmanifest.xml file. SCORM does not have any control over how the server handles MIME types. If you are running a local server (including servers that might be built-in to tools), you will need to configure it to handle the MIME types in question.

For example:

- Apache: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html
- IIS: http://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config

Comment: Yes. I was checking if this is true. So couldn't accept it immediatelly before check.